# Python 3 dict behavior in Python 2

Tags: python, dictionary

I saw [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26271/cleaner-way-to-import-izip-for-different-versions-of-python?noredirect=1#comment40684_26271) tonight. I had never heard of `future_builtins` before this, and it got me wondering. `future_builtins` only covers a few types, and `dict` is not one of them. Is there a way to use the Python 3 `dict` behavior that uses views for `items`, `keys`, and `values` in Python 2.7? This would be especially useful when trying to write Python 3 compatible code. In Python 2, these methods have the overhead of creating `list`s, and the iterator versions go away in Python 3. Yet using them is the recommendation for writing Python 3 compatible code.

Comment: Similar thing was proposed but they preferred adding `viewkeys()` as  methods to `dict` over `from __future__ import ..`, http://bugs.python.org/issue1967

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `viewkeys()`, `viewitems()` and `viewvalues()` in py2x.

```
>>> dict.viewkeys?
Type:       method_descriptor
String Form:<method 'viewkeys' of 'dict' objects>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:  D.viewkeys() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's keys
```

[What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) :

> - dict methods `dict.keys()`, `dict.items()` and `dict.values()` return    “views” instead of lists. For example, this no longer works: `k = d.keys()`; `k.sort()`. Use `k = sorted(d)` instead (this works in Python 2.5 too and is just as efficient).
> - Also, the `dict.iterkeys()`, `dict.iteritems()` and `dict.itervalues()` methods are no longer    supported.

Bug : [Backport dictviews to 2.7](http://bugs.python.org/issue1967):

> After talking to Guido, got rid of the future import magic in favour
>   of just providing `viewkeys`, `viewitems` and `viewvalues` methods of
>   dicts. This makes efficient 2.6-and-3.0 `dict`-using code possibly by
>   making `2to3` translate the `view`-methods directly to `keys`/`values`/`items`
>   in
>   3.0, and not wrapping everything in `list()`.

`2to3` tool:

```
RefactoringTool: Refactored so.py
--- so.py   (original)
+++ so.py   (refactored)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-print dic.viewkeys()
+print(dic.keys())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like these go away in Python 3, too. Bummer. (Sorry for the sneaky edit while you were answering.)

Comment: @jpmc26 yes, these were replaced my `keys()`,`values()` in py3x.

Comment: @jpmc26 you can use the `2to3` tool, write the code in py2x and get it's equivalent py3x version.

Comment: Guess that's as close as it'll get to being the same in Python 2 and 3. Thanks!