# python 'dict' object has no attribute 'viewkeys'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

i am newbie in python and i was running program and maybe it is written in python2.X which is provided by my friend,

but it was not running because i was getting error of `dict object has no attribute viewkeys` originally when i have ran the script error was as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 236, in <module>
    for key in (Data_Pe.keys() | Data.viewkeys()):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'viewkeys'
```

in it `Data_pe` and `Data` both are `dict` object.

Comment: see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16601275/10197418) - it's `.viewkeys()` in Python2 and `.keys()` in Python3 but it seems not to be possible to use both methods alongside each other (also not using an `or` operator `|`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried to find on stackoverflow but i have not found any question related to this so i have asked and answered it myself, i have found the answer on the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/2to3.html?highlight=viewkeys) which was as below

> **dict**
>
> Fixes dictionary iteration methods. `dict.iteritems()` is converted
> to `dict.items()`, `dict.iterkeys()` to `dict.keys()`, and `dict.itervalues()`
> to `dict.values()`. Similarly, `dict.viewitems()`, `dict.viewkeys()` and
> `dict.viewvalues()` are converted respectively to `dict.items()`,
> `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()`. It also wraps existing usages of
> dict.items(), dict.keys(), and dict.values() in a call to list.

so in short in python3.X version it is changed from :

**`dict.viewkeys()` to `dict.keys()`**